# Testing if method is called using Mockito

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, mockito

I have a menu which calls different operations based on choice given to it. I want to use mockito to see if the proper method is called.
This is my implenetation so far...

Menu.java:

My menu takes in options and instances of the different options.

eg. printItemOfTypeBook is an instance of PrintBookOperation.

```
    private void setMenuOptions() {
        char keyForPrintingBooks = '1';
        char keyForPrintingMovies = '2';
        char keyForAccountLogin = '3';
        char keyForExit = '4';
        menuOptions.put(keyForPrintingBooks, printItemsOfTypeBook);
        menuOptions.put(keyForPrintingMovies, printItemsOfTypeMovie);
        homeMenuOptions.put(keyForAccountLogin, loginAccount);
        homeMenuOptions.put(keyForExit, quit);
    }
```

I then pass a character to the apply choice method which finds the appropriate instance and calls execute on it.

```
    public void applyChoice(char choice) {
        if ((!menuOptions.containsKey(choice)) && (!homeMenuOptions.containsKey(choice))) {
            new WrongChoiceOperation();
        }
        if (menuOptions.containsKey(choice)) {
            menuOptions.get(choice).execute(library, reader, writer);
        }
        if (homeMenuOptions.containsKey(choice)) {
            homeMenuOptions.get(choice).execute(library, reader, writer);
        }
    }
}
```

I am testing the first option which is printing books. So I mock the PrintBookOperation class and check if the execute method in it is called.

PrintBookOperation.java:

```
    @Override
    public void execute(Library library, Input reader, Output writer) {
        this.library = library;
        this.writer = writer;
        printBooks();
    }

    private void printBooks() {
        writer.formattedHeadings();
        List<Lendable> items = library.listItems();
        items.stream().filter(item -> item.isOfType(Book)).forEach(item -> {
            writer.write("\n" + item.toFormattedString());
        });
    }
}
```

My Test :

```
    @Test
    public void isThePrintOperationCalled() {
        Input reader = new ConsoleInput();
        Output writer = new ConsoleOutput();
        PrintBooksOperation print = mock(PrintBooksOperation.class);
        Book book = new Book("nin", "#123", "ghy", 2003);
        Library library = new Library(new LinkedList<>(singletonList(book)));
        Menu menu = new Menu(reader, writer, library);
        menu.applyChoice('1');
        verify(print).execute(library, reader, writer);
    }

}
```

My Error Message :

```
Wanted but not invoked:
printBooksOperation.execute(
    tw51.biblioteca.Library@39c0f4a,
    Mock for Input, hashCode: 1471868639,
    Mock for Output, hashCode: 876563773
);
-> at tw51.biblioteca.io.menu.home.MenuTest.isThePrintOperationCalled(MenuTest.java:30)
Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock.
```

What am I doing wrong?? How do I correct this??

Comment: You're mocking a `PrintBooksOperation`, but then you're not using it at all. And finally, you `verify` that the `execute` method was called, so this can't work (since it was never called). What are you actually trying to do and test? Also, please cut down the code to a [mcve], there is too much unrelated code here.

Comment: That said, it's pretty clear that you're not doing **anything** with `print`, thus no methods will ever be called on it.

Comment: @Oliver The code runs and prints correctly. Just want to check it with mockito.

Comment: My first menu option is printItemsOfTypeBook which is an instance of PrintBookOperation class. So the logic os when i pass '1' to apply choice. it should call execute and then print

Comment: I checked with the debugger option as you suggested as well..It gets called

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating a mock for the PrintBooksOperation class (called print), but the mock is not sent on to the class being tested at all. Therefore, mockito throws an exception, because the *execute* function was never called on the mock.

I would suggest changing your Menu class so that you inject

- printItemsOfTypeBook
- printItemsOfTypeMovie
- loginAccount
- quit

rather than allocating new instances inside Menu.java. You can do something like this:

```
public class Menu {
     public Menu(Input reader, 
                Output writer, 
                Library library, 
                PrintBooksOperation printItemsOfTypeBook, 
                PrintMoviesOperation printItemsOfTypeMovie, 
                LoginAccountOperation loginAccount, 
                QuitOperation quit) {
           this.reader = reader;
           this.writer = writer;
           this.library = library;
           this.printItemsOfTypeBook = printItemsOfTypeBook;
           this.printItemsOfTypeMovie = printItemsOfTypeMovie;
           this.loginAccount = loginAccount;
           this.quit = quit;
     }
}
```

(Note I guessed the class names of your other operation classes above). Now in your test class, you can do the following:

```
    PrintBooksOperation print = mock(PrintBooksOperation.class);
    Menu menu = new Menu(reader, writer, library, print, null, null, null);
    menu.applyChoice('1');
    verify(print).execute(library, reader, writer);
```

The verification should now work correctly.

Basically it makes unit testing a lot easier if you use dependency injection for your units.